# Direct2D - Emulating Color Keyed Transparent Bitmaps

Tags: c++, transparency, gdi, direct2d

I'm currently updating a Windows GDI application to use Direct2D rendering and I need to support "transparent" bitmaps via color-keying for backwards compatibility.

Right now I'm working with a HWND render target and a converted WIC bitmap source (to GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA).  My plan so far is to create a IWICBitmap from the converted bitmap, Lock() it, and then process each pixel setting it's alpha value to 0 if it matches the color key.

This seems a bit "brute force" - Is this the best method of approaching this or is there a better way?

Edit: In the interests of completeness here's an extract of what I went with - looks like it's working fine but I'm open to any improvements!

```cpp
// pConvertedBmp contains a IWICFormatConverter* bitmap with the pixel 
// format set to GUID_WICPixelFormat32bppPBGRA

IWICBitmap* pColorKeyedBmp = NULL;
HRESULT hr    = S_OK;
UINT    uBmpW = 0;
UINT    uBmpH = 0;

pConvertedBmp->GetSize( &uBmpW, &uBmpH );

WICRect rcLock = { 0, 0, uBmpW, uBmpH };

// GetWIC() returns the WIC Factory instance in this app
hr = GetWIC()->CreateBitmapFromSource( pConvertedBmp, 
                                       WICBitmapCacheOnLoad, 
                                       &pColorKeyedBmp );
if ( FAILED( hr ) ) {
   return hr;
}

IWICBitmapLock* pBitmapLock = NULL;
hr = pColorKeyedBmp->Lock( &rcLock, WICBitmapLockRead, &pBitmapLock );
if ( FAILED( hr ) ) {
   SafeRelease( &pColorKeyedBmp );
   return hr;
}

UINT  uPixel       = 0;
UINT  cbBuffer     = 0;
UINT  cbStride     = 0;
BYTE* pPixelBuffer = NULL;

hr = pBitmapLock->GetStride( &cbStride );
if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {
   hr = pBitmapLock->GetDataPointer( &cbBuffer, &pPixelBuffer );
   if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ) ) {

      // If we haven't got a resolved color key then we need to
      // grab the pixel at the specified coordinates and get 
      // it's RGB

      if ( !clrColorKey.IsValidColor() ) {
         // This is an internal function to grab the color of a pixel
         ResolveColorKey( pPixelBuffer, cbBuffer, cbStride, uBmpW, uBmpH );
      }

      // Convert the RGB to BGR
      UINT   uColorKey = (UINT) RGB2BGR( clrColorKey.GetRGB() );
      LPBYTE pPixel    = pPixelBuffer;

      for ( UINT uRow = 0; uRow < uBmpH; uRow++ ) {

         pPixel = pPixelBuffer + ( uRow * cbStride );

         for ( UINT uCol = 0; uCol < uBmpW; uCol++ ) {

            uPixel = *( (LPUINT) pPixel );

           if ( ( uPixel & 0x00FFFFFF ) == uColorKey ) {
              *( (LPUINT) pPixel ) = 0;
           }
           pPixel += sizeof( uPixel );
        }
     }
   }
}

pBitmapLock->Release();

if ( FAILED( hr ) ) {
   // We still use the original image
   SafeRelease( &pColorKeyedBmp );
}
else {
   //  We use the new image so we release the original
   SafeRelease( &pConvertedBmp );
}

return hr;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to "process" the bitmap to render it, then the fastest is always GPU. In Direct2D there are [effects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh973240.aspx) (ID2D1Effect) for simple bitmap processing. You *can* write your own [it seems comparatively complicated], or use one of the [built-in effects](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh706316.aspx) [which is rather simple]. There is one called [chroma-key (CLSID_D2D1ChromaKey)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn890715.aspx).

On the other hand, if you need to do further processing on CPU, it gets more complex. You might be better off optimizing the code you have.