# Proper syntax of Direct2D Chroma-Key effect

Tags: direct2d, visual-studio-2015, visual-c++-2015

I'm trying to implement a Croma-Key effect on a bitmap, and i'm following the page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn890715(v=vs.85).aspx
first i noticed the syntax was incorrect in the implementation of an array as an argument, when i fixed this, the proper way to get the processed image was incorrect and needed some poling around to solve, in the end, i'm still unable to find what m_d2dContext is. i would assume it's the ID2D1HwndRenderTarget but the intelesense says there's no method definition for: `CreateEffect` i was wondering if anyone has had success with this, and could show and explain their code.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [what's the proper implementation of the Chroma-key Effect in Microsoft visual studio c++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966439/whats-the-proper-implementation-of-the-chroma-key-effect-in-microsoft-visual-st)

Answer (score 0):

I do, as I already replied to the same question you posted 4 days ago: [what's the proper implementation of the Chroma-key Effect in Microsoft visual studio c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38966439/whats-the-proper-implementation-of-the-chroma-key-effect-in-microsoft-visual-st)